# Как упростить алгоритм определения сектора по углу и расстоянию?

Tags: java, android, c++, алгоритм

Использую [вот этот "виртуальный джойстик"](https://github.com/controlwear/virtual-joystick-android) для android приложения. Необходимо перевести данные от джойстика (он может дать: угол 0-359 и расстояние 0-99) в однозначное направление(право, право-вверх, вперед, лево-вверх, лево итд).

Например, разделить круг на равные части и каждой из пар присвоить направление.
Что-то из серии:

```
string temp(double value){
    string str = "";
    if (value <= 1 || value >= 15)
        str = "право";
    else if (value <= 2)
        str = "право вверх";
    else if (value <= 4)
        str = "прямо";
    else if (value <= 6)
        str = "лево вверх";
    else if (value <= 8)
        str = "лево";
    else if (value <= 10)
        str = "лево назад";
    else if (value <= 12)
        str = "назад";
    else if (value <= 14)
        str = "назад право";
    return str;
}

int main(){
  int value = 240; // от 0 до 359
  cout << temp(value / 22.5);
}
```

**UPD:**
Получается так. Еще бы без повторов.. Но так тоже неплохое упрощение.

```
string str[] = {"R", "U R", "U R", "F", "F", 
                "U L", "U L", "L", "L", 
                "D L", "D L", "D", "D", 
                "D R", "D R", "R"};

int main(){
  int value = 240; // от 0 до 359
  cout << str[(int)(value / 22.5)];
}
```

**UPD1:**
Или я не правильно понимаю идею комментария или правда не работает

```
string str[] = {"R", "U R","F", "U L", "L", "D L", "D", "D R"};

string str_dbl[] = {"R", "U R", "U R", "F", "F", 
                "U L", "U L", "L", "L", 
                "D L", "D L", "D", "D", 
                "D R", "D R", "R"};

int main(){
  int value;
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    value = rand() % 358 + 1;
    cout << i << '\t' << value << '\t';
    cout << str_dbl[(int)(value / 22.5)] << "\t:\t";
    cout << str[(int)((value - 22.5) / 45)] << endl;
  }
}

// 0       172     L       :       U L                                                                                                                                                
// 1       263     D       :       D L                                                                                                                                                
// 2       308     D R     :       D                                                                                                                                                  
// 3       212     D L     :       L                                                                                                                                                  
// 4       92      F       :       U R
```

Comment: Без повторов - сделайте `str[(int)((value - 22.5) / 45)];`

Comment: Не работает так

Comment: "Не работает так" - ***как*** не работает?

Comment: Привел пример UPD1

Comment: Подсказываю ... Обратите внимание, что результаты смещены ровно на 1 сектор .. что нужно поменять, чтобы смещение пропало? .... Может быть сдвинуть строки в массиве по кругу на 1 позицию ... или вместо -22,5 сделать +22,5 ? И еще, вспомните про деление по модулю .. чтобы 359+22,5 превратилось в 21,5 ... а не было 381,5

Comment: Не обратил внимание на смещение. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо [Serodv](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/261878/serodv) и [Kromster](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177188/kromster). Конечный вариант:

```
string str[] = {"R", "U R","F", "U L", "L", "D L", "D", "D R"};

int main(){
    int value = 240; // от 0 до 359
    cout << str[(( (int)(value + 22.5) ) % 360) / 45];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Массив сделайте из 16-ти элементов `String[] str = {"право", "право вверх", "право вверх", ..., "назад право", "право"}` и вынимайте строку из него `return str[(int) value]`